# Merge overlapped intervals in a list

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list of intervals:

```
{{1,10},{8,15},{17,22},{24,36},{32,40}}
```

I want to merge overlap pairs. For example, the first and second pairs are overlapping, so I want them to be change to: {1,15}.

The new list I would like to have is:

```
{{1,15},{17,22},{24,40}}
```

Any suggestions ?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Invoking [`Interval`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Interval.html) auto-simplifies and sorts the components:

```
Interval @@ {{1, 10}, {8, 15}, {17, 22}, {24, 36}, {32, 40}}
(*    Interval[{1, 15}, {17, 22}, {24, 40}]    *)
```

To get back to the list format,

```
List @@ Interval @@ {{1, 10}, {8, 15}, {17, 22}, {24, 36}, {32, 40}}
(*    {{1, 15}, {17, 22}, {24, 40}}    *)
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: @GM_jnj You're welcome. The preferred way of giving thanks on StackExchange is to accept an answer by clicking the green check mark.